# System Status page empty and status remains 'critical' after updating from 4.7.8 to 4.7.11 on Drupal 6

Tags: error, upgrade, drupal-6

This is a Drual 6 site with internationalization enabled for CiviCRM. There are no extensions installed. Site was updated from 4.7.8 to 4.7.11.

After running the db update script, the System Status in the footer has remained "Critical", despite the only red flag prior to the update being that the site needed to be updated.

When visiting the System Status page, it no longer displays any setting statuses, including the usual greens for php version, etc.

After running the db update script for 4.7.11 there were no errors on the update screen - back on the dashboard, however, the widgets failed to load and there was a DB error, but refreshed the page and it went away (and widgets came back) and hasn't come back since. The logs showed the DB error was due to a timezone error (I can paste the log details if desired).

The timezone issue is not appearing in a pop-up as (like I've seen on other sites), it is unknown if the error is the cause of what's breaking the system status page as I have been ignoring the timezone issue since it's not critical. Either way, this does not explain why the system status is now displaying as critical.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Update: issues still present in 4.7.14

Comment: I see someone else has found the timezone error after the update, so this may be related to this issue: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14841/error-datetimezone-construct-unknown-or-bad-timezone-7200

Comment: To clarify, the DB error appears on the screen the first time visiting the dashboard after logging-in (each time you log-in). After that, it appears only in the logs while visiting the broken system status page.

Comment: Also on D6 and Civi 4.7.11. My system status page does not populate on opening.  I see the system status page url in the CiviCRM footer is civicrm/a/#/status, but when opening it resolves to civicrm/a#/status (no foreward slash between a and #.

Comment: Not an answer. Can't comment, because I am not good enough to do so. Here is an error Detail report Log: $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] => CRM_Core_Error [1] => exceptionHandler ) [code] => a515ac9c2796ca0e23adbe92c68fc9fc [message] => DB Error: a515ac9c2796ca0e23adbe92c68fc9fc [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => SET time_zone = '-28800:00' [nativecode=1298 ** Unknown or incorrect time zone: '-28800:00'] [type] => DB_Error [user_info] => SET time_zone = '-28800:00' [nativecode=1298 ** Unknown or incorrect time zone: '-28800:00'] [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: a

Comment: In my case this was related to the [timezone error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14841/error-datetimezone-construct-unknown-or-bad-timezone-7200) and fixing the time zone error allowed the messages to display. I just answered the fix for the time zone issue over there.

Answer (score 1):

For some the answer has been to resolve the Timezone error, if it is present - see: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14841/error-datetimezone-construct-unknown-or-bad-timezone-7200

If you have stumbled upon this thread more recently - we found a blank status page after a recent upgrade from 4.6.30 to 4.7.27 where there was no timezone error, in fact, no errors at all in the logs. The solution was to change "Asset caching" from "Auto" to "Disable" (/civicrm/admin/setting/debug?reset=1).