# Why are my Actions drop downs not working post civicrm security update?

Tags: angular

After the CiviCRM security updates - some of our D8 sites are throwing blanks when selecting an Action -> on e.g. the Search -> Contacts Results screen.

Select Contacts -> Select Action -> Nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

Another clue: the CiviCRM -> Status page `/civicrm/a#/status` was completely blank

This helped [it's a cache clear of sorts]

`Administer -> System Settings -> Asset Caching -> Disable`

brought both Actions as well as the Status page back. Then was able to toggle it back to -> `Auto`

For one project I also had to re-run `composer civicrm:publish` (some bower assets - only some - most were there) - were just not there post upgrade.

Most sites upgraded just fine. Not sure what was/is different about the three sites I ran into this issue with. I wonder if it's redis... [I usually blame caching ]

Comment: You just helped me fix another site that wasn't loading the civicrm status page. I ran `composer civicrm:publish` and it fixed it - how did you know about/find that command?

Comment: I’ve run into this before -> js error shows 404s  - missing assets / sub directories -> try again -> civicrm:publish